# nginx proxy_pass for a web application

Tags: nginx

**What I have:**

nginx installed on host `my-host`; 
a web-application available at `http://my-host:3012`

**What I want:**

access the web-application at http://my-host/my-app

**What I tried**

In `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    ...
    location /my-app/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3012/;
    }
}
```

After this the app can't access part of it's resources. Relative resources like

`<script src="js/external/jquery.min.js"></script>`

is mapped to `http://my-host/my-app/js/external/jquery.min.js` and this works.

Absolute resources like

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

are mapped to `http://my-host/socket.io/socket.io.js` when `http://my-host/my-app/socket.io/socket.io.js` was expected

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Well - you state that you want to run the application as `http://my-host/my-app`. Then why your absolute URLs do not start with `/my-app` ?

Comment: The application is not something I should/want to change. I took it from github and it should work as is.